# Perdurantism applied to non-physical objects

Tags: metaphysics, ontology, time

I have recently been reading up a lot on perdurantism aka four dimensionalism including papers by Rea, Sider, Bittner and Donnelly among others and I was interested in knowing whether there was any systematic treatment in the literature of perdurantism as applied to non-physical things (i.e., things that don't necessarily have any spatial dimension) such as artistic compositions (paintings, novels, etc that can potentially change over time or have different versions), laws and conventions, etc?

Comment: The conventional view is that to the extent that paintings, novels, etc., exist in time they are physical objects, and exist also in space, and to the extent that they do not, i.e. speaking of something like their "ideas", they are abstract and hence timeless. See, however, [Caplan-Matheson, Defending Musical Perdurantism](http://bdcaplan.ca/defending_musical_perdurantism.pdf) and [Aliyev's critique](https://brill.com/view/journals/gps/94/1-2/article-p83_83.xml).

Comment: thanks...this is an excellent lead!